# setTimeout in For loop not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, settimeout, discord

In my Discord.js bot, I am trying to create a spam command that will send a message every 3/4 of a second (750ms). However, it'll wait 3/4 of a second before sending the first message, but will stop waiting for the rest of the messages; literally spews out messages like crazy. How can I fix this?
https://pastebin.com/qdTV2Hre

```
function doSetTimeout(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        message.channel.send(msg);
    }, 750);
}
for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    message.channel.startTyping();
    doSetTimeout();
    message.channel.stopTyping();
}
```

Comment: Your code sets up a bunch of timeouts to happen at exactly the same time, 750 milliseconds in the future.

Comment: Do you realize that the stopTyping() will be called before the send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` - doesn't waits - it returns timeout handler immediately, so you running 10 times `startTyping() ... stopTyping()`, than after 750ms 10 times `send(msg)`.

If you want to wait 750ms between messages you may try following:

```
function writeSomething(n) {
  if(n>0) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        message.channel.startTyping();
        message.channel.send(msg);
        message.channel.stopTyping();
        writeSomething(n-1)
    }, 750);
  }
}

writeSomething(10)
```

Comment: For what the OP is trying to accomplish, this is probably the best solution.  I am assuming `message` is an object that requires synchronous actions, e.g. `startTyping`, then `send`, then `stopTyping`.   The other approaches here, depending on how the JavaScript event loop appears, would either be `startTyping`, `stopTyping`, `send`x3, or something along those lines.  This approach appears to preserve the order of (`startTyping`, `send`, `stopTyping`)x3.

Comment: Logic is very simple and it works the way I want it to! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the delay according the loop, in other words you need to make it a multiple of `i`, so each iteration comes after the previous one respecting its delay.

```
function doSetTimeout(delay){
    setTimeout(function(){
        message.channel.send(msg);
    }, (delay+1)*750);
}
for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    message.channel.startTyping();
    doSetTimeout(i);
    message.channel.stopTyping();
}
```

A sample **Demo:**

```js
function doSetTimeout(delay){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //message.channel.send(msg);
        console.log('Message '+delay);
    }, (delay+1)*750);
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //message.channel.startTyping();
    doSetTimeout(i);
    //message.channel.stopTyping();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `doSetTimeout()` is being called `times` number of times synchronously. So let's say the `for` loop takes 5ms to complete, you'd expect the first `setTimeout` to take 750ms but then the rest will happen within 5ms of each other.

There are two possible solutions:

1) Initiate the `setTimeout` from within it's own callback. Now each concurrent `setTimeout` will only be initiated upon completion of the previous:

```
var count = 0

function doSetTimeout(){
  if (count < times) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      count++;
      message.channel.send(msg);
      doSetTimeout();
    }, 750);
  }
}
```

2) You could also use a similar approach with `setInterval`:

```
var count = 0
var timer

function doSetTimeout(){
  timer = setInterval(function(){
    if (count < times) {
      count++;
      message.channel.send(msg);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, 750);
}
```